# mapreduce job stuck at 0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I had this strange error where my mapreduce job always got stuck at map 0% reduce 0%. So I went on to do some research and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525354/map-reduce-job-getting-stuck-at-map-0-reduce-0) which did solve my problem when I ran the hadoop tasktracker & on the namenode, but according to my knowledge Namenode only supports a JobTracker and in some cases Secondary NameNode. TaskTrackers are for DataNodes right? Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.
Why do I have to start tasktracker daemon on the NameNode everytime?

And Is there a permanent solution to make this automatic because everytime I have manually start off the TaskTracker on the NameNode.

Comment: You should start the task traker only once.by the script in hadoop/bin/start-all.sh.If task tracker is not starting you should check the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible that you're Mapping Task is stuck in an infinite loop.  The percentage is the percent of Map Tasks that are completed.  If every time you submit a Map Job the mapping is stuck in an infinite loop, its never gonna be able to be completed.

Comment: The Mapping task runs fine when I enable the TaskTracker on the NameNode, and that too manually. What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: If the map task is running fine with the configuration you set up then what's the problem now?

Comment: Everytime I have to manually start up the tasktracker on the namenode. Can this be done through some configuration settings? Am I missing some configuration settings?